# How to find number if percentage is known

Tags: percentages

`10.5% = 1.0` and `100%  = 9.0`
How to find number which is equal to `27.36%` from this range?

Comment: $0.2736 \times 9$

Comment: I like to think of $\%$ as an abbreviation of division by $100$.

Comment: @GitGud Thinking of percents as division is probably the best way to think about them :D

Comment: @gitgud indeed this way of viewing things demystifies the meaning of $120\%$

Comment: I just realised my comment is completely out of place. I hadn't read the question properly.

Comment: @GitGud Lol, and we all think your comment was great XD

Comment: @SimpleArt xD ${{{}}}$

Comment: Are you sure these numbers are correct? if $10.5\% = 1.0$, then $100\%=9.52 \neq 9.0$. Please fix the percentages, otherwise there are two different answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple.  If you meant $100\%=9$, then

$$27.36\%=\frac{27.36}{100}\times100\%=0.2736\times9=2.4624$$

If, however, you meant $10.5\%=1$, then

$$27.36\%=\frac{27.36}{10.5}\times10.5\%=2.6057$$

Comment: Then `1.0` will not be equal to `10.5%` but will be equal to `0.9`

Comment: @RomanBanakh :-( hm, you can't simultaneously have $10.5\%=1$ and $100\%=9$ then.

Comment: @SimpleArt See my comment on the original post. The percentages you gave aren't right Roman, they both belong to different original amounts.

Comment: @AndrewTawfeek I suppose I fixed it, accounting both cases...

Comment: @SimpleArt Awesome :) Although I think OP was expecting one answer, so either he copied down the problem wrong or he misunderstood the problem

Comment: @AndrewTawfeek well, I got it right now either way I'd hope

Comment: Thanks guys for fast response. Probably I have made some mistake somewhere in my calculations.

Comment: @RomanBanakh Ok, well, hope it doesn't ruin anything.

Comment: Just someone's life. But don't worry it will be bad guy :D